# How to add rich text into CoreData and then print?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to save rich text to CoreData and then print it out.

What kind of text do I want? ->
1. Font color
2. Bold
3. Underline
3. Links
4. Font size

How can I do that?

P.S. in the "web world" you put "<strong>bold text</strong> and etc."

Comment: If you mean print it out in an iOs app then using html is actually your best bet.  Then you display it in a web view.

Comment: Have maybe link to some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a very simple example.  In your case you simply would store the html string into your core data model and then display it like i do below.

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    NSString *htmlRichText = @"<html><body><p><strong>HEY</strong> here's some text</p></body></html>";
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlRichText baseURL:nil];

}


@end
```